# how to append text into an edittext in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application I want to give the user ways of selecting text from a list and appending into an edittext, however Im unable to find any documentation on how to do this, any help would go a long way, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use append() of the EditText. The Argument will be appended at the end of the Editable.

Comment: Thanks for the response seems straight forward but I wasnt able to see this in the documentation for some odd reason? either way It works thank you very much!