# How to frequently update number in EditText from loop?

Tags: java, android

My Code should frequently update a number (not only show the result, delay of 100) from a loop in an EditText after you click on a button.

Old Code:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        while (repeat > 0) {
            num1 = new Random().nextInt(6)+1;
            edit1.setText(String.valueOf(num1));
            repeat = repeat - 1;
            rep.setText(String.valueOf(repeat));
        }
    }
});
```

Now I have this:

```java
final Handler randomHandler = new Handler();

final Runnable randomUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        num1 = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
        edit1.setText(String.valueOf(num1));

        repeat--;
        rep.setText(String.valueOf(repeat));

        randomHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

btnpl5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        repeat = repeat + 5;
        rep.setText(String.valueOf(repeat));
        button2.setClickable(true);
        button2.setEnabled(true);
    }
});

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    randomUpdate.run();
    button2.setClickable(false);
    button2.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Problem: it won't stop after repeat is 0 (it goes on -1 -2 -3 -4 ..)?

Comment: Are you looking to append? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981334/how-to-append-text-into-an-edittext-in-android

Comment: It should set every new number into EditText from while loop.

Comment: How long of a delay and when should this happen?

Comment: Delay of 100 and after every random number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AsyncTask` to delay in the background, and `publishProgress()` to update the UI.

```
class TextDisplayTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {

    private int DELAY_MILLIS = 100; // ... set your delay here

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        for (int i = 0; i < params[0]; i++) {
            int num = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
            publishProgress(num);
            Thread.sleep(DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        edit1.setText(String.valueOf(values[0]));
    }
}

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new TextDisplayTask().execute(20);  // show a number 20 times
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

> You must always be on the UI thread when calling any method on any
>   view. If you are doing work on other threads and want to update the
>   state of a view from that thread, you should use a Handler.

Try this,

```
   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            num1 = new Random().nextInt(6)+1;
            // get previous value and append new generated
             edit1.setText(edit1.getText().toString()+String.valueOf(num1)); 
            }
   }, (1000)); // run this method in every 1000 milliseconds
```

This may help you.